# iOS: drawbacks of disabling Metal API Validation in order to fix pipeline failed assertion?

Tags: ios, animation, sprite-kit, scenekit, metal

Adding a `SKEmitterNode` to a SceneKit Scene via a SpriteKit overlay generates the following exception:

> -[MTLDebugRenderCommandEncoder validateFramebufferWithRenderPipelineState:]:1196: failed assertion
>   `For color attachment 0, the render pipeline's pixelFormat
>   (MTLPixelFormatRGBA8Unorm_sRGB) does not match the framebuffer's
>   pixelFormat (MTLPixelFormatBGR10_XR).'

This exception occurs on an iPhone 7 device, but does not appear in the simulator.

Searching online yielded one valid workaround: disabling `Metal API Validation` (in Edit Scheme > Options).

What are the drawbacks or gotchas with this workaround?

The obvious benefit is the app now works, but what's the cost?

Comment: You are going to have issues with color, can’t you use scenekits emitter, SCNParticleSystem

Comment: SpriteKit's emitter creates a flatter look -- ideal for this case -- and is roughly the same size no matter how zoomed in the camera is.

Comment: @Knight0fDragon what color issues are you referring to? The colors don't appear different so far ...?

Comment: You are mixing bgr onto rgb, so your blues are red and your reds are blue,  plus bgr10 is fixed point from -.75 to 1.25

Comment: @Knight0fDragon is there another workaround you propose? Why does disabling the API validation change the colors?

Comment: When your colors are blending, you are blending the red channel to the blue channel, not red channel to red channel,  the validation is doing what it is suppose to be doing, validating that you are using the same color space to ensure correct blending.  If it was simple rbg8 to bgr8 I would tell you to just sway red and blue on your particles to get the correct blending, but the 10bit fixed point is really screwing things up,  blending 8 to 10 means your alpha is getting improperly blended as well.

Comment: @Knight0fDragon thanks for the explanation, and sorry for the newb questions. if we aren't seeing any color differences now, are you just saying it's a matter of time before there are differences? how could we force these differences to surface? more importantly, what are the alternatives for using SKEmitterNodes in a SceneKit scene?

Comment: The color difference may not be noticeable because the blend is negligible,  a good way to test is to blend red and blue.  If you get red you have a problem, if you get purple your color is correct.  For all we know, apple fixes the color space after the validation instead of before.

Comment: @Knight0fDragon thanks! one more stupid q ... how do you blend red and blue as you propose for the test?

Comment: Have your scenekit show a blue cube, and use red particles.  You need alpha at 50% on the particles

Comment: @Knight0fDragon ok thanks! will test this.

Comment: OK ran a test with a blue background for the scene with red particles with 50% alpha. the particles showed up red. does this mean it's okay? @Knight0fDragon

Comment: in your SceneKit project, there is a settings.json.  Set compress textures to false and see if that fixes your problem

Comment: How did such a thing happen? Do the Sprite Kit and Scene Kit teams live in different silos?

Comment: @Confused yes it seems like they do, unfortunately. :( they're all talented but understaffed. wish tim cook would spend some of the $300B on helping to bolster those teams and fix these frustrating API issues.

Comment: @Knight0fDragon where do you see "settings.json"? it doesn't appear anywhere? what if we never need to blend colors and everything will be 100% alpha. will this be okay? for instance, the red particles appeared red -- not purple -- but this was fine because we made the particles red.

Comment: it is where ever your scene file is located at,  should be an assets folder of some kind, like scnassets. In regards to your question about 100% alpha,  I really wish I understood what is going on better, because in theory your blue cube should have turned red, or your red particles turn blue because of how the frame buffer is laid out, so I have no idea what the heck kind of conversions apple is doing.  At the end of the day, as long as it looks the way you want it to look, I say run with it.