# SCNView.present alternative?

Tags: ios, scenekit

Since SCNView.present does not work** on an iPad Pro or iPhone X running iOS 11 (at least thru 11.3), does anyone have a suggestion for an alternative way to provide a smooth transition when changing scenes? I'd be happy with a simple fade or crossfade.  Thanks!

** In release mode it makes a mess of the colors and in debug mode with Metal API validation enabled, it asserts with a Metal color format mismatch error:

-[MTLDebugRenderCommandEncoder validateFramebufferWithRenderPipelineState:]:1196: failed assertion `For color attachment 0, the render pipeline's pixelFormat (MTLPixelFormatRGBA8Unorm_sRGB) does not match the framebuffer's pixelFormat (MTLPixelFormatBGR10_XR_sRGB).'

UPDATE: Apple suggested that as a temporary workaround, set SCNDisableWideGamut to YES in the app's Info.plist file. It seems to work for me - no more asserts or incorrect colors.